# SQL - One row for each name

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, amazon-aurora

Trying to utilise the technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/123481 I'm attempting to retrieve one row for each `name`, with a particular sort, namely the top/first row after sorting in descending order by `active`, `created`, then `prid`. However the `active` column may contain numberic or `NULL` values, which is causing a duplicate in the `name=bat` case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Source table:

```
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| prid | name  | active | created |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| 1    | bat   | NULL   | 3       |
| 2    | bat   | 1      | 2       |
| 3    | bat   | 2      | 1       |
| 4    | bat   | 3      | 0       |
| 5    | noise | NULL   | 2       |
| 6    | noise | NULL   | 1       |
| 7    | cup   | NULL   | 0       |
| 8    | cup   | NULL   | 0       |
| 9    | egg   | 4      | 4       |
| 10   | egg   | 4      | 2       |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
```

Desired result:

```
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| prid | name  | active | created |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| 9    | egg   | 4      | 4       |
| 4    | bat   | 3      | 0       |
| 5    | noise | NULL   | 2       |
| 8    | cup   | NULL   | 0       |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
```

SQL:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM source_table p1
LEFT JOIN source_table p2 ON (
  p1.name = p2.name
  AND (
    p1.active < p2.active
    OR (
      (p1.active = p2.active OR (p1.active IS NULL AND p2.active IS NULL))
      AND (
        p1.created < p2.created
        OR (
          p1.created = p2.created AND p1.prid < p2.prid
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
WHERE p2.prid IS NULL
ORDER BY p1.active DESC, p1.created DESC, p1.prid DESC
```

Actual result:

```
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| prid | name  | active | created |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
| 9    | egg   | 4      | 4       |
| 4    | bat   | 3      | 0       |
| 1    | bat   | NULL   | 3       |
| 5    | noise | NULL   | 2       |
| 8    | cup   | NULL   | 0       |
+------+-------+--------+---------+
```

---

**@Gordon Linoff**

Thanks for the help, I try to use the second version with the indexes `(name, active, created, prid)` and `(active, created, prid)`, however it's being quite slow.

This takes 1 second, returns the right results, but in the wrong order:

```
SELECT t1.prid
FROM source_table t1
WHERE t1.prid = (
  SELECT t2.prid
  FROM source_table t2
  WHERE t2.name = t1.name
  ORDER BY t2.active DESC, t2.created DESC, t2.prid DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
LIMIT 50
```

And this takes 55 seconds:

```
SELECT t1.prid
FROM source_table t1
WHERE t1.prid = (
  SELECT t2.prid
  FROM source_table t2
  WHERE t2.name = t1.name
  ORDER BY t2.active DESC, t2.created DESC, t2.prid DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY t1.active DESC, t1.created DESC, t1.prid DESC
LIMIT 50
```

And really I need `LIMIT 500`, any ideas?

---

**@Rick James**

SQL Fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9b39/2/0

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I was trying to keep it database agnostic, but I guess if I can get something working for MySQL variants that would be a good start.

Comment: How many rows in the 'source' table?

Comment: **@Rick James** Around 6 million at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ANSI-standard `row_number()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name
                                order by active desc, created desc, pid desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from source_table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

The above works in MySQL 8+ and MariaDB 10.2+.  In earlier versions, you can do:

```
select t.*
from source_table t
where t.prid = (select t2.prid
                from source_table t2
                where t2.name = t.name
                order by t2.active desc, t2.created desc, t2.pid desc
                limit 1
               );
```

For performance, you want an index on `source_table(name, actdive desc, created desc, pid desc, prid)`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I updated my question with the results of your suggestion, any tips on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(active,  -1) DESC,
         IFNULL(created, -1) DESC,
         IFNULL(pid,     -1) DESC,
```

**Full Stmt**

```
SELECT  prid, name, active, created
    FROM  
        ( SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(prid
                    ORDER BY  IFNULL(active,  -1) DESC,
                              IFNULL(created, -1) DESC,
                              IFNULL(prid,    -1) DESC 
                              ) AS ids
            FROM  source_table
            GROUP BY  name 
        ) AS s1
    JOIN  source_table AS s2
        ON s2.prid = SUBSTRING_INDEX(s1.ids, ',', 1)
    ORDER BY  IFNULL(active,  -1) DESC,
              IFNULL(created, -1) DESC,
              IFNULL(prid,    -1) DESC ;
```

Comment: Please provide sqlfiddle so we can experiment.

Comment: @Jason - OK, I had to fold in some "groupwise max" code to get it to work.

Comment: Tried your updated code, but it suffers from the same issue as Gordon Linoff's did, that being it returns the correct results, but in the wrong order.

Comment: @Jason - Oops, I needed to add a copy of the `ORDER BY`.  Try again.